# Gerar número aleatório sem repetição em C

Tags: c, memória, random, números-aleatórios

Olá, 
estou fazendo um jogo de memória em c, e gostaria de saber como gerar um número aleatório sem repetição. Vou postar o que na função até o momento. Precisarei fazer outra função somente para verificar se existe número repetido?

```
void preencher_mesa(int matriz[4][4], int dificuldade)
{

    int i,j;
    int lim_col, lim_linha;



    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
            matriz[i][j] = 0;


    if(dificuldade == 1)
    {
        lim_col = 3;
        lim_linha = 2;

    }
    else if(dificuldade == 2)
    {
        lim_col = 4;
        lim_linha = 2;
    }
    else if(dificuldade == 3)
    {
        lim_col = 4;
        lim_linha = 4;
    }

    srand(time(NULL) );
    for(i=0;i<lim_linha;i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<lim_col;j++)
        {
                if(dificuldade == 1)
                {
                    matriz[i][j] = (rand()%3)+1;

                }
                else if(dificuldade == 2)
                {
                    matriz[i][j] = (rand()%6)+1;


                }
                else if (dificuldade == 3)
                {
                    matriz[i][j] = (rand()%8)+1;

                }



        }

    }

     mostrar_mesa(matriz);
}
```

Comment: Nao podes meter os valores `1`, `2`, e `3` num array de 6 posicoes sem repetir! (dificuldade == 1); Nao podes meter os valores `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, e, `6` num array de 8 posicoes sem repetir! (dificuldade == 2); nao podes meter 8 valores num array de 16 posicoes sem repetir (3)

Comment: Na verdade quero que eles repitam, mas uma vez só, por se tratar de um jogo de memória

Comment: Ok, a ideia é a mesma da minha resposta. Enches o array com valores repetidos, baralhas o array, usas os valores aleatorios.

Comment: Acabei criando essa variável: int cartas[16] = {1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8}; na main. Porém eu gostaria que de acordo com o nível de dificuldade estivessem somente um casal de cartas. Exemplo => Dificuldade 1 -> 3 pares de cartas então aparecesse somente (randomicamente) sei lá, 1 e 1 , 4 e 4 , 7 e 7 @pmg

Comment: A maneira mais facil 'e apanhares 3 numeros isolados para o principio dum array (`{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}` ==> `{1, 4, 7}`); depois extender esse principio de array (`{1, 4, 7}` ==> `{1, 4, 7, 1, 4, 7}`); e finalmente baralhar o array. Nota que o array pode ser sempre (ou quase sempre) o mesmo, apenas muda o numero inicial que consideras. Ve o edit da minha resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Metes todos os numeros possiveis num array; baralhas esse array; depois usas os valores necessarios.

```
int valores[] = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
                 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
                 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29}; // 18 valores, para 16 posicoes
shuffle(valores); // ver, por exemplo, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = valores[4*i + j];
    }
}
```

---

*Edit*

Para preencher o array consoante o grau de dificuldade podes fazer

```
for (i = 0; i < lim_col * lim_linha; i++) valores[i] = i / 2 + 1;
```

---

*2o edit*

Fiz um programa que faz o que pretendes.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int randto(int n) {
    int r, rmax = (RAND_MAX / n) * n;
    do r = rand(); while (r >= rmax);
    return r % n;
}

void shuffle(int *data, int n) {
    while (n > 1) {
        int p = randto(n--);
        int tmp = data[n];
        data[n] = data[p];
        data[p] = tmp;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc != 2) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    int carta[16];
    int base[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    int n;
    int dificuldade;
    srand(time(0));
    dificuldade = atoi(argv[1]);
    switch (dificuldade) {
        default: return 1; break;
        case 1: n = 3; break;
        case 2: n = 5; break;
        case 3: n = 8; break;
    }

    shuffle(base, sizeof base / sizeof *base);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) carta[i + n] = carta[i] = base[i];
    shuffle(carta, 2 * n);

    printf("Seq:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) printf(" %d", carta[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

O output com diferentes parametros foi

```
% ./a.out 3
Seq: 2 7 8 3 6 1 4 1 5 5 7 6 8 3 4 2
% ./a.out 2
Seq: 1 5 7 1 5 8 4 4 7 8
% ./a.out 1
Seq: 5 2 6 6 2 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a função `srand((unsigned) time(NULL))`, como exemplificado abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    const int MAX = 10;
    int i;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        printf("Elemento %d = %d\n", i, rand()%MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

Com esse código, será impresso 10 números na tela e todos estão entre 0 e 9, inclusive.

Comment: Para os curiosos: `srand` vem de _seed random_ /semear o aleatório. O algoritmo de número aleatório do `rand` trabalha em gerar um novo número em cima da semente anterior, daí ele atualiza a semente para usar novamente